# Getting trace to store a value in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am running the `nloptr` package in `R` which is a package for nonlinear optimization. Within the `nloptr` package I am using the `cobyla()` command to perform my optimization.  Now, I can specify the maximim number of iterations of the algorithm using the `maxeval` parameter, but when `cobyla()` command executes it only allows me to see the output for the final evaluation.  However, I would like to be able to see all of the outputs at every iteration of the method.

Someone recommended to me that I use the `trace()` command to be able to see all of the intermediary output but I cannot figure out how to get `R` to store this information.  Can anyone suggest to me how to accomplish this using `trace()` (or any other way).

Here is the code I am working with:

```
library(nloptr)


#########################################################################################
### 
#########################################################################################
f = function(x){
    ans = cos(pi*x/5)+.2*sin(4*pi*x/5)

    return(ans)
}

const = function(x){
    ans = numeric(1)
    ans[1] = -(sin(pi*x/5)+.2*cos(4*pi*x/5))
    return(ans)
}

#########################################################################################
###
#########################################################################################

x0 = runif(1,0,10)

COB = cobyla(x0,f,hin=const,lower=0,upper=10,nl.info = TRUE,
      control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 2000))
```

So I would like to be able to store the output for running `cobyla()` for iterations 1,2,...,maxeval

And so what I would think I would need to do is use

```
trace(f)
```

or

```
trace(cobyla)
```

before executing the code but I am not sure how to store the values of running the `trace()` command

Comment: I'd imagine the optimization's iteration loop is being carried out by compiled C or Fortran code in the underlying NLopt library, so R's `trace()` won't be able to help you access those intermediate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet, without tweaking the `nloptr` code, is to set the `print_level` option to `3`, send the output to a `sink` and scrape it to retrieve what you need.

Note that to use `print_level` you cannot use the wrapper function `cobyla` -- instead you have to drop down to the `nloptr` function.

Lastly, note that the `cobyla` and the `nloptr` function with `algorithm = NLOPT_LN_COBYLA`, behave differently -- the former takes inequality constraints to be >= 0 and the latter takes them to be <=0.

---

In the code below, the first thing I do is to use the core `nloptr` function and show that it leads to the same answer as using the `cobyla` wrapper code.

Then, I set `print_level = 3` and write that out to a file. Once the optimization is done, I read that file in, and use regular expressions to extract the solution path from the output.

Here is what that looks like: 
[image]

```
library(tidyr)
library(nloptr)
library(assertthat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# starting parameter values
x0.hs100 = c(1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1)

# objective function
fn.hs100 = function(x) {
  (x[1]-10)^2 + 5*(x[2]-12)^2 + x[3]^4 + 3*(x[4]-11)^2 + 10*x[5]^6 +
    7*x[6]^2 + x[7]^4 - 4*x[6]*x[7] - 10*x[6] - 8*x[7]
}

# inequality constraints
# NOTE: nloptr with algorithm = NLOPT_LN_COBYLA takes g(x) <= 0
hin.hs100 = function(x) {
  h = numeric(4)
  h[1] = 127 - 2*x[1]^2 - 3*x[2]^4 - x[3] - 4*x[4]^2 - 5*x[5]
  h[2] = 282 - 7*x[1] - 3*x[2] - 10*x[3]^2 - x[4] + x[5]
  h[3] = 196 - 23*x[1] - x[2]^2 - 6*x[6]^2 + 8*x[7]
  h[4] = -4*x[1]^2 - x[2]^2 + 3*x[1]*x[2] -2*x[3]^2 - 5*x[6]    +11*x[7]
  return(-h)
}

# compute the solution
sink(file = "Output/cobyla_trace.txt", type = "output")
S1 = nloptr(x0 = x0.hs100, 
            eval_f = fn.hs100,
            eval_g_ineq = hin.hs100,
            opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA", 
                        xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 2000, print_level = 3))
sink()

# inequality constraints
# NOTE: cobyla takes g(x) >= 0
hin.hs100_minus = function(x) {
  h = numeric(4)
  h[1] = 127 - 2*x[1]^2 - 3*x[2]^4 - x[3] - 4*x[4]^2 - 5*x[5]
  h[2] = 282 - 7*x[1] - 3*x[2] - 10*x[3]^2 - x[4] + x[5]
  h[3] = 196 - 23*x[1] - x[2]^2 - 6*x[6]^2 + 8*x[7]
  h[4] = -4*x[1]^2 - x[2]^2 + 3*x[1]*x[2] -2*x[3]^2 - 5*x[6]    +11*x[7]
  return(h)
}

# compute the solution
S2 = cobyla(x0.hs100, fn.hs100, hin = hin.hs100_minus,
            nl.info = TRUE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 2000))

# check that both return the same solution
assertthat::are_equal(S1$solution, S2$par)

# get the solutions from the output file
solutionPath = readLines(con = file("Output/cobyla_trace.txt"))

# extract the solution path data out of the raw output
solutionPathParamRaw = solutionPath[grepl("^\tx", solutionPath)]
solutionPathParamMatch = gregexpr("(-)?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?", solutionPathParamRaw, perl = TRUE)
solutionPathParam = as.data.frame(
  t(
    sapply(
      regmatches(
        solutionPathParamRaw, solutionPathParamMatch
      ), 
      as.numeric, simplify = TRUE
    )
  )
)

# give the columns some names
names(solutionPathParam) = paste("x", seq(1, 7), sep = "")
solutionPathParam$IterationNum = seq(1, dim(solutionPathParam)[1])

# plot the solutions
solutionPathParam %>%
  gather(Parameter, Solution, -IterationNum) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = IterationNum, y = Solution, group = Parameter, color = Parameter)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()

ggsave("Output/SolutionPath.png")
```

Comment: this code works beautifully.  But how can I modify the code to also save the value of the objective and constraint functions at each iteration?  That's actually more important to me than to have the param values.

Comment: If I didn't want to use the COBYLA method, say for example instead I wanted to use the MMA method, then I would specify `algorithm = NLOPT_LD_MMA`, but how do I specify the gradient information?  I am having a hard time with this because my `fn.hs100` isn't a an analytical function but rather a computer simulation that I give an input to and it gives me back an output, but I don't actually know the analytical form of it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Josh is right in his comment then you'll need to do the looping yourself.  It would look something like this...

```
maxeval<-2000
x0<-c()
x0[1] = runif(1,0,10)
for (cureval in 1:maxeval) {
    COB = cobyla(x0[cureval],f,hin=const,lower=0,upper=10,nl.info = TRUE,
      control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-16, maxeval = 1))
    x0[cureval+1]  <-COB$par

  }
```