# Plotting newton-raphson/fisher scoring iterations in R

Tags: r, glm, newtons-method

Is there a package in R plotting newton-raphson/fisher scoring iterations when fitting a glm modelel (from the stats package)?

Comment: as i know, there aren't any special plotting packages, so, you can, obviously, using, for example, ggplot2. It's a great package with big amount of capabilities.
For more details of R plotting packages, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750153/relationship-between-plotting-packages-in-r

Comment: thank you for the hint. But I was more looking for a package or R-code which extracts the iterations when fitting a glm and plots them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered a very similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33636588/1414455). In your case however, things are a little simpler.

Note that when you call `glm`, it eventually calls `glm.fit` (or any other `method` argument you specify to `glm`) which computes the solution path in the loop from lines 78 to 170. The current iteration's value of the coefficients is computed on line 97 using a `.Call` to a C function `C_Cdqrls`. As a hack, you can extract the current value of the coefficients to the global environment (`fit$coefficients`), within this loop, by modifying the `glm.fit` function like so:

```
glm.fit.new = function (x, y, weights = rep(1, nobs), start = NULL, etastart = NULL, 
                        mustart = NULL, offset = rep(0, nobs), family = gaussian(), 
                        control = list(), intercept = TRUE) {
                          control <- do.call("glm.control", control)
                          x <- as.matrix(x)
                          xnames <- dimnames(x)[[2L]]
                          ynames <- if (is.matrix(y)) 
                            rownames(y)
                          else names(y)
                          conv <- FALSE
                          nobs <- NROW(y)
                          nvars <- ncol(x)
                          EMPTY <- nvars == 0
                          if (is.null(weights)) 
                            weights <- rep.int(1, nobs)
                          if (is.null(offset)) 
                            offset <- rep.int(0, nobs)
                          variance <- family$variance
                          linkinv <- family$linkinv
                          if (!is.function(variance) || !is.function(linkinv)) 
                            stop("'family' argument seems not to be a valid family object", 
                                 call. = FALSE)
                          dev.resids <- family$dev.resids
                          aic <- family$aic
                          mu.eta <- family$mu.eta
                          unless.null <- function(x, if.null) if (is.null(x)) 
                            if.null
                          else x
                          valideta <- unless.null(family$valideta, function(eta) TRUE)
                          validmu <- unless.null(family$validmu, function(mu) TRUE)
                          if (is.null(mustart)) {
                            eval(family$initialize)
                          }
                          else {
                            mukeep <- mustart
                            eval(family$initialize)
                            mustart <- mukeep
                          }
                          if (EMPTY) {
                            eta <- rep.int(0, nobs) + offset
                            if (!valideta(eta)) 
                              stop("invalid linear predictor values in empty model", 
                                   call. = FALSE)
                            mu <- linkinv(eta)
                            if (!validmu(mu)) 
                              stop("invalid fitted means in empty model", call. = FALSE)
                            dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
                            w <- ((weights * mu.eta(eta)^2)/variance(mu))^0.5
                            residuals <- (y - mu)/mu.eta(eta)
                            good <- rep_len(TRUE, length(residuals))
                            boundary <- conv <- TRUE
                            coef <- numeric()
                            iter <- 0L
                          }
                          else {
                            coefold <- NULL
                            eta <- if (!is.null(etastart)) 
                              etastart
                            else if (!is.null(start)) 
                              if (length(start) != nvars) 
                                stop(gettextf("length of 'start' should equal %d and correspond to initial coefs for %s", 
                                              nvars, paste(deparse(xnames), collapse = ", ")), 
                                     domain = NA)
                            else {
                              coefold <- start
                              offset + as.vector(if (NCOL(x) == 1L) 
                                x * start
                                else x %*% start)
                            }
                            else family$linkfun(mustart)
                            mu <- linkinv(eta)
                            if (!(validmu(mu) && valideta(eta))) 
                              stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some", 
                                   call. = FALSE)
                            devold <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
                            boundary <- conv <- FALSE

                            # EDIT: counter to create track of iterations
                            i <<- 1
                            for (iter in 1L:control$maxit) {
                              good <- weights > 0
                              varmu <- variance(mu)[good]
                              if (anyNA(varmu)) 
                                stop("NAs in V(mu)")
                              if (any(varmu == 0)) 
                                stop("0s in V(mu)")
                              mu.eta.val <- mu.eta(eta)
                              if (any(is.na(mu.eta.val[good]))) 
                                stop("NAs in d(mu)/d(eta)")
                              good <- (weights > 0) & (mu.eta.val != 0)
                              if (all(!good)) {
                                conv <- FALSE
                                warning(gettextf("no observations informative at iteration %d", 
                                                 iter), domain = NA)
                                break
                              }
                              z <- (eta - offset)[good] + (y - mu)[good]/mu.eta.val[good]
                              w <- sqrt((weights[good] * mu.eta.val[good]^2)/variance(mu)[good])
                              fit <- .Call(stats:::C_Cdqrls, x[good, , drop = FALSE] * 
                                             w, z * w, min(1e-07, control$epsilon/1000), check = FALSE)

                              #======================================================
                              # EDIT: assign the coefficients to variables in the global namespace
                              #======================================================
                              assign(paste0("iteration_x_", i), fit$coefficients, 
                                     envir = .GlobalEnv)
                              i <<- i + 1   # increase the counter

                              if (any(!is.finite(fit$coefficients))) {
                                conv <- FALSE
                                warning(gettextf("non-finite coefficients at iteration %d", 
                                                 iter), domain = NA)
                                break
                              }
                              if (nobs < fit$rank) 
                                stop(sprintf(ngettext(nobs, "X matrix has rank %d, but only %d observation", 
                                                      "X matrix has rank %d, but only %d observations"), 
                                             fit$rank, nobs), domain = NA)
                              start[fit$pivot] <- fit$coefficients
                              eta <- drop(x %*% start)
                              mu <- linkinv(eta <- eta + offset)
                              dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
                              if (control$trace) 
                                cat("Deviance = ", dev, " Iterations - ", iter, 
                                    "\n", sep = "")
                              boundary <- FALSE
                              if (!is.finite(dev)) {
                                if (is.null(coefold)) 
                                  stop("no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values", 
                                       call. = FALSE)
                                warning("step size truncated due to divergence", 
                                        call. = FALSE)
                                ii <- 1
                                while (!is.finite(dev)) {
                                  if (ii > control$maxit) 
                                    stop("inner loop 1; cannot correct step size", 
                                         call. = FALSE)
                                  ii <- ii + 1
                                  start <- (start + coefold)/2
                                  eta <- drop(x %*% start)
                                  mu <- linkinv(eta <- eta + offset)
                                  dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
                                }
                                boundary <- TRUE
                                if (control$trace) 
                                  cat("Step halved: new deviance = ", dev, "\n", 
                                      sep = "")
                              }
                              if (!(valideta(eta) && validmu(mu))) {
                                if (is.null(coefold)) 
                                  stop("no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values", 
                                       call. = FALSE)
                                warning("step size truncated: out of bounds", 
                                        call. = FALSE)
                                ii <- 1
                                while (!(valideta(eta) && validmu(mu))) {
                                  if (ii > control$maxit) 
                                    stop("inner loop 2; cannot correct step size", 
                                         call. = FALSE)
                                  ii <- ii + 1
                                  start <- (start + coefold)/2
                                  eta <- drop(x %*% start)
                                  mu <- linkinv(eta <- eta + offset)
                                }
                                boundary <- TRUE
                                dev <- sum(dev.resids(y, mu, weights))
                                if (control$trace) 
                                  cat("Step halved: new deviance = ", dev, "\n", 
                                      sep = "")
                              }
                              if (abs(dev - devold)/(0.1 + abs(dev)) < control$epsilon) {
                                conv <- TRUE
                                coef <- start
                                break
                              }
                              else {
                                devold <- dev
                                coef <- coefold <- start
                              }
                            }
                            if (!conv) 
                              warning("glm.fit: algorithm did not converge", call. = FALSE)
                            if (boundary) 
                              warning("glm.fit: algorithm stopped at boundary value", 
                                      call. = FALSE)
                            eps <- 10 * .Machine$double.eps
                            if (family$family == "binomial") {
                              if (any(mu > 1 - eps) || any(mu < eps)) 
                                warning("glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred", 
                                        call. = FALSE)
                            }
                            if (family$family == "poisson") {
                              if (any(mu < eps)) 
                                warning("glm.fit: fitted rates numerically 0 occurred", 
                                        call. = FALSE)
                            }
                            if (fit$rank < nvars) 
                              coef[fit$pivot][seq.int(fit$rank + 1, nvars)] <- NA
                            xxnames <- xnames[fit$pivot]
                            residuals <- (y - mu)/mu.eta(eta)
                            fit$qr <- as.matrix(fit$qr)
                            nr <- min(sum(good), nvars)
                            if (nr < nvars) {
                              Rmat <- diag(nvars)
                              Rmat[1L:nr, 1L:nvars] <- fit$qr[1L:nr, 1L:nvars]
                            }
                            else Rmat <- fit$qr[1L:nvars, 1L:nvars]
                            Rmat <- as.matrix(Rmat)
                            Rmat[row(Rmat) > col(Rmat)] <- 0
                            names(coef) <- xnames
                            colnames(fit$qr) <- xxnames
                            dimnames(Rmat) <- list(xxnames, xxnames)
                          }
                          names(residuals) <- ynames
                          names(mu) <- ynames
                          names(eta) <- ynames
                          wt <- rep.int(0, nobs)
                          wt[good] <- w^2
                          names(wt) <- ynames
                          names(weights) <- ynames
                          names(y) <- ynames
                          if (!EMPTY) 
                            names(fit$effects) <- c(xxnames[seq_len(fit$rank)], rep.int("", 
                                                                                        sum(good) - fit$rank))
                          wtdmu <- if (intercept) 
                            sum(weights * y)/sum(weights)
                          else linkinv(offset)
                          nulldev <- sum(dev.resids(y, wtdmu, weights))
                          n.ok <- nobs - sum(weights == 0)
                          nulldf <- n.ok - as.integer(intercept)
                          rank <- if (EMPTY) 
                            0
                          else fit$rank
                          resdf <- n.ok - rank
                          aic.model <- aic(y, n, mu, weights, dev) + 2 * rank
                          list(coefficients = coef, residuals = residuals, fitted.values = mu, 
                               effects = if (!EMPTY) fit$effects, R = if (!EMPTY) Rmat, 
                               rank = rank, qr = if (!EMPTY) structure(fit[c("qr", "rank", 
                                                                             "qraux", "pivot", "tol")], class = "qr"), family = family, 
                               linear.predictors = eta, deviance = dev, aic = aic.model, 
                               null.deviance = nulldev, iter = iter, weights = wt, prior.weights = weights, 
                               df.residual = resdf, df.null = nulldf, y = y, converged = conv, 
                               boundary = boundary)
                        }
```

Note that this is a hack for a couple of reasons:
1. The function `C_Cdrqls` is not exported by the package `stats`, and so we have to look for it within `namespace:package:stats`.
2. This pollutes your global environment with the iteration values via a side-effect of the call to `glm.fit.new`, creating one vector per iteration. Side-effects are generally frowned upon in functional languages like R. You can probably clean the multiple objects bit up by creating a matrix or a `data.frame` and assign within that.

However, once you have the iteration values extracted, you can do whatever you want with them, including plotting them.

Here is what a call to `glm` with the newly defined `glm.fit.new` method would look like:

```
counts = c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome = gl(3,1,9)
treatment = gl(3,3)
print(d.AD = data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 = glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson(), 
               control = list(trace = TRUE, epsilon = 1e-16), method = "glm.fit.new")
```

You can check that the iteration parameter values have indeed been populated in the global environment:

```
> ls(pattern = "iteration_x_")
 [1] "iteration_x_1"  "iteration_x_10" "iteration_x_11" "iteration_x_2" 
 [5] "iteration_x_3"  "iteration_x_4"  "iteration_x_5"  "iteration_x_6" 
 [9] "iteration_x_7"  "iteration_x_8"  "iteration_x_9"
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your quick and detailed answer. One quick question though. When I follow your suggestions and fit the glm with the new method typ, I only get the deviance for each iteration. Do you by chance know, how I get the estimated parameters themselves? Since, I want to plot them, this would be really helpful! Thanks again, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @PatrickBalada My guess is that you are looking at what is printed to the console. As I mentioned in my answer -- the parameters are not printed and are contained in the objects with names `iteration_x_*`.

Comment: @PatrickBalada Try `t(sapply(ls(pattern = "iteration_x"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)), simplify = TRUE))`.

Comment: Awesome - works perfect! Thank you so much! Great help!